# What is the SQL Server services credentials usage?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

What's the importance of changing SQL Server service credentials login ?
[image]
Can we leave it as the default builtin account or shall we change it with something **DOMAIN\username** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to run SQL Server using LocalSystem accounts. You may find these links useful.

[Picking Service Accounts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/pickingserviceaccounts/2351/)

[Selecting an Account for the SQL Server Agent Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/changing-service-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

That is specified for Service start/stop authority. Above services will be authorised as specified user for service start/stop status. You should leave this as it is as because at the time of SQL installation that users like NETWORK SERVICE | LOCAL SERVICE are already assigned required permissions to perform act. Also if you want you can change service credentials but make sure that domain account or Local Account has required permissions to start or stop service.